# Doing the same analysis for many variables and plotting them

Tags: r, plot, statistics, analysis

My Dataset consists of about 180 variables and as I used SPSS for data input (so I can run the analysis in SPSS, if my first attempt using R takes too long / doesn't work) I had to recode lots of -99 and "kA" to "NA".

So I ended up with copy/pasting the `recode()` funtion a lot, adding the according variable to it. There must be smarter ways to handle problems like that - right?

I want to create a line diagram, that shows the opinion of my pollees, consisting of the mean of their responses.
Each pollee was asked his/her opinion on several items and rated them on a scale from 1-10. So I'd like to see the average score for each item, seeing if people tend to more agree/disagree on it.  *(I hope this added information helped to understand the issue a bit better).*  Again - with about 20 or so questions/item for this part, there should be a smarter approach than writing code for every single variable.

I also wonder how I'd get the results in a useful shape, so I can work with the resulting means - preferably plotting them with ggplot2 as line diagram(s). The plotting itself shouldn't be too much of a problem (even though I appreciate any hints and tips!) - the main problem here is, how to get the resulting data (the means) into a shape, that continuing to process them (creating a graph, subsetting) is possible/easy. So far, the approach in my workgroup was (using SPSS) copying the result, pasting into Excel and fiddling around there.

Comment: There is a `matplot` function if you are trying to plot multiple lines. You can either search the web or SO to find many worked examples. If you post an adequate description of how this data is organize you may get more specific answers. Use the edit facility rather than responding with comments. You could probably have done all the recode with two short lines: `dfrm[dfrm=="-99"] <- NA; dfrm[dfrm=="kA"] <- NA`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment and your advice regarding the dfrm function (which I've never heard of so far...)

Comment: `dfrm` is not a function. The only functions are `==` and `[<-`. Since you didn't offer an example I just made up a name. I use "dfrm" to signify a dataframe, rather than the more typical but flawed (IMO) use of "df". Since `df` is the density function for the F distribution, I find it annoying that so many people use 'df' as their favorite generic object name. I may get over my annoyance in a few more years.

Answer (score 0):

If you enter your data in SPSS, you can define missing values there. You can then use packages like, e.g `haven` or `sjmisc` to read the SPSS file, where missing values are automatically converted to `NA`.

If you want to do some recodes afterwards, you may also look at `rec` from the `sjmisc` package, which allows to recode a complete data frame at once (so no need to copy the recode command and replace with new variable names each time). See following example:

```
library(sjmisc)
data(efc)
head(efc[, 6:9])
```

> ```
>   c82cop1 c83cop2 c84cop3 c85cop4
> 1       3       2       2       2
> 2       3       3       3       3
> 3       2       2       1       4
> 4       4       1       3       1
> 5       3       2       1       2
> 6       2       2       3       3
> ```

```
head(rec(efc[, 6:9], "1=10;2=20;3=30;4=40"))
```

> ```
>   c82cop1 c83cop2 c84cop3 c85cop4
> 1      30      20      20      20
> 2      30      30      30      30
> 3      20      20      10      40
> 4      40      10      30      10
> 5      30      20      10      20
> 6      20      20      30      30
> ```

According to the mean values of responses: If I understood right, you would like to have the mean value for each question / variable for all observations? If yes, you can simply use the `colMeans` function. An example from the efc-data set of the sjmisc-package, where variables 6 to 14 are used (all items have a 4-item-response-scale):

```
library(sjmisc)
data(efc)
mydf <- efc[, 6:14]
colMeans(mydf, na.rm = T)

>  c82cop1  c83cop2  c84cop3  c85cop4  c86cop5  c87cop6  c88cop7  c89cop8  c90cop9 
> 3.118757 2.024390 1.634146 1.768374 1.394678 1.288889 1.923333 2.164262 2.932432
```

If you want to plot these mean values, simply create a data frame and use ggplot like this:

```
plot.df <- data.frame(x = as.factor(c(1:ncol(mydf))),
                      y = colMeans(mydf, na.rm = T))
ggplot(plot.df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

For a line plot, `x` needs to be numeric:

```
plot.df <- data.frame(x = c(1:ncol(mydf)),
                      y = colMeans(mydf, na.rm = T))
# You may want to adjust the scale for proper values
ggplot(plot.df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1:ncol(mydf)))
```

[image]